# Conditional ModRewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a conditional rule if it matches (images, stylesheets, javascript) then do nothing to the url, if url does not include donate the change from https to http

Her is what I have now.

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} images [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} stylesheets [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} javascript
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !donate
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !donate
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.creative-capital.org$1/ [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but for starters, QUERY_STRING only includes what comes after the ? in the url.  If that's not what you want, then you probably want to use THE_REQUEST.  Also, why don't you just place all of your conditions (in the negative) on the second rule instead of creating a "do nothing" rule.